# Websocket with Django channels doesn't work, connection failed

Tags: django, websocket, redis, django-channels, daphne

**Hello Awesome People!**

I created a chat room with `django-channels`. Every time I try to connect to my chat room via web socket in production, it fails.
Locally it works correctly.

I host on **digitalocean**

pip freeze:

```
channels==2.1.2
channels-redis==2.3.0
daphne==2.2.1
'''
```

I have installed the `redis-server` with

```
sudo apt-get install redis-server
```

Here's my settings.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # '''
   'channels',
    # '''
] 
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            "hosts": [os.environ.get('REDIS_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379')],
        },
    },
}
ASGI_APPLICATION = "project_name.routing.application"
```

Here's my `asgi.py` alongside `wsgi.py`

```
import os
import django
from channels.routing import get_default_application

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project_name.settings")
django.setup()
application = get_default_application()
```

And here's my `project_folder.rounting.py`

```
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'websocket':AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
        AuthMiddlewareStack(
            URLRouter([
                # my urls
            ])
        )
    )
})
```

I keep getting this in firefox and something similar in other browsers:

> Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://www.domain_name.com/url-to/1/XBvZjr2pqdf6fhy/

However it works locally.

UPDATE

Here is my js

```
var loc = window.location;
var wsStart = loc.protocol == "https:" ? "wss://" : "ws://"
var endpoint = wsStart + loc.host + loc.pathname
var socket = new ReconnectingWebSocket(endpoint);

socket.onmessage = function(e){
    // code
}
```

Comment: I've been trying to figure this out for over a month now /= 
Are you deployed on Ubuntu?

Comment: Hi @Eu Chi ... I see you're on a wss (secure websocket) connection...have you secured it, and secured it for the correct port? What happens if you move everything to regular old ws?

Comment: Yes i am using Ubuntu @Mint

Comment: Thanks for asking @MichaelRoberts , I am using SSL connection, if I try with ws without it, the connection is refused by saying *The connection is insecure*

Comment: Does your normal https://www. subdomain all work ok?

Comment: And is port 6379 all open and working ok?

Comment: Yes, The site was running properly and I had used *js DOM refreshed* for the chat room until I decided to go with ws.

Comment: Not sure if this is of any help: https://github.com/django/channels/issues/514

Answer (score 17):

I finally fixed the problem and make `ws` used under `ssl` connection with `wss://`.

For those that are facing the same issue.

Note that I use

- `gunicorn` as web server only for `http` request
- `daphne` as web server for `ws` web socket
- `nginx` as reverse proxy

`asgi.py`

```
import os
import django
from channels.routing import get_default_application

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project.settings")
django.setup()
application = get_default_application()
```

`settings.py`

```
ASGI_APPLICATION = "project.routing.application"

CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            "hosts": [(os.environ.get('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost'),6379)],
        },
    },
}
```

After setting up the `asgi` with django, I use `supervisorctl` to keep `daphne` running. Create a file `daphne_asgi.conf` in `/etc/supervior/conf.d/`

**daphne_asgi.conf**

```
[program:asgi_daphne]

directory=/path/to/your/project

command=/executable/path/to/daphne --bind 0.0.0.0 --port 8010 project.asgi:application
# 0.0.0.0 ip of your website
# I choose the port 8010 for daphne

stdout_logfile=/path/to/log/daphne.log

autostart=true

autorestart=true

redirect_stderr=true
```

run the following to update launch the daemon

```
sudo supervisorctl reread
sudo supervisorctl update
```

Here is the configuration of `nginx`

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    '' close;
}
upstream websocket {
    server 0.0.0.0:8010;
}
```

host and port used in daphne ... `--bind 0.0.0.0 --port 8010`

```
#redirection to a https
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 0.0.0.0 example.com www.example.com;
    client_max_body_size 10M;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    server_name www.example.com;
    client_max_body_size 10M;

    # ssl configuration
    ...

    # normal http request, I use .sock
    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/path/to/project.sock;
    }

    # ws request /ws/
    location /ws/ {
        proxy_pass http://websocket;

         # this magic is needed for WebSocket
        proxy_http_version  1.1;
        proxy_set_header    Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header    Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header    Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

Note that I added `/ws/` in my ws urls

```
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({

    'websocket':AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
        AuthMiddlewareStack(
            URLRouter(
                [
                    url(r'^ws/$', HelloConsumer),
                ]
            )
        )
    )
})
```

Comment: You don't need to do `python manage.py runworker channels -v2` in supervisor?

Answer (score 2):

Most important, Use redis 5.0.9. Otherwise again error will be there.

Get it from [github.com/tporadowski/redis/releases](https://github.com/tporadowski/redis/releases)